# Keypad Freezing Up - think it's a Touch Wiz issue? (can I get around this with a Launcher?)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, keyboard, launcher, system-freeze, samsung-touchwiz

I would be grateful for some feedback/suggestions.

In short, I have an ageing (badly) Android 4.4.4 - Samsung Galaxy Ace 4, AVG and some Avast Apps on the Virus Checker side, and Touch Wiz.

Something that has happened since Day 1 is occasionally when using Social Media Messaing apps on data (e.g. Whatsapp and Signal in data mode, never happens in SMS) occassionally the keypad will just totally lock up (e.g. be visible, but won't take any input or I will get a delayed input, and it won't pick up the right letter - e.g. tapped 3 times for a "C" and I get an "A" - 45 seconds later).

When I re-start the phone, everything is back to normal (until the next time it happens - which is never far away - e.g. no more than 15 messages).

I have done a little reading around and someone suggested clearing the Touch Wiz Cache which did seem to help and delayed the re-occurance of the problem (I don't know why?).

From doing a little more reading it seemed that I may be able to get around this by using a Launcher (e.g. Nova) to bypass Touch Wiz (which doesn't seem to have a lot of fans).

Would this be the case or have I misdiagnosed the problem?

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Is the issue related to the keyboard or the launcher? Is this happening with another keyboard also? I cannot imagine the launcher doing this... Try Google Now launcher.

Comment: @esQmo sorry for the late response on this. The launcher switch made minimal difference. It still freezes up, just less regularly. I can work around it, it is just annoying 